# Android PagerView between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe

I have five activities/screens that I would like to be able to swipe between, each has a different function but are interrelated hence the UI concept of swiping between each.

I have found many discussions around ViewPager and PagerAdapters etc. but cannot seem to find one where swiping switches between different activity screens.

Is this even possible? Could someone point me towards an example project of this with source code? Or show me how to adapt an existing tutorial to do what I wish?

Thanks so much, have a good one!

Comment: I cannot point you towards an example with activities. I can provide a code example of an application that uses Compatibility Pack Action Bar Tabs and Fragments with a ViewPager, if you like. Basically, each tab is a fragment, hosted in one main activity (my app is steadily growing other activities for other tasks, though). But you'd have to be willing to use fragments, not activities. Interested?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't use `ViewPager` to swipe between `Activities`. You need to convert each of you five `Activities` into `Fragments`, then combine everything in one `FragmentActivity` with the `Adapter` you use with `ViewPager`.

[Here's a link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-working-with-fragments--mobile-5367) that goes into detail on converting your current `Activities` info `Fragments`.

This is the [Fragment topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) on the Android Developers website, it has a lot of useful info.

[Here's another example](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/) (full source) that inflates `TextViews` on each page.

Here's an example that I typed up:

**PagerAdapter**:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

**This should be called in `onCreate` of your `FragmentActivity`**:

```
    private void initPaging() {

    FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
    FragmentTwo fragmentTwo= new FragmentTwo();

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentOne);
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentTwo);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
```

**This is an example of the layout you'd use for your `FragmnetActivity`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To create `Fragment` create a new class that extends `Fragment`. The first two methods you'll want to `override` are `onActivityCreated` and `onCreateView`.

**Here's how you could do that:**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(THE_LAYOUT_FROM_YOUR_ORIGINAL_ACTIVITY, container, false);
    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Found this through google; I keep getting an error when setting the adapter: "this.mPagerAdapter". "mPagerAdapter cannot be resolved or is not a field". This is the only error I have. mPagerAdapter works in the PagerAdapter.  No idea how to fix it. If I remove the "this." I get a warning that the initialisePaging() isn't used locally. Appreciate any help from those that see this

Comment: I have one question, Aneal, How can I add a new fragment to this adapter from FragmentOne? Because I have this fragment "sort of home screen" and if I click something there, then it takes me to other screen, in this case, another fragment and so on... How can i achieve this?

Comment: getItem(int position) is getting called twice and thus giving indexOutOfBound exception ...

Comment: To add to the accepted answer one can alternatively use `PagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` to switch between Views instead of Fragments.

Answer (score 2):

Fix For mPageradapter

```
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentOne);
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentEvents);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

Comment: getItem(int position) is getting called twice and thus giving indexOutOfBound exception