# How to make right or left or left to right transition between activities on sliding the screen

Tags: android, android-activity, touch, screen, sliding

If I have three activities, I want to move from one activity to another when touching the moving on the screen horizontally(from left to right or right to left). how to access the action of sliding the screen and  ?

Comment: [You should consider using `Fragments` and `ViewPager`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9849234/420015)

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
     try    {           
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewActivity.class);    
        startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);        
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

and

http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/