# Android: how to slide between activites?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, scrollview, slide

I want to scroll between views. Actually, I don't know what to use: HorizontalScrollView or Activities?

I want to slide between my layouts:

[image]

Am I need to implement GestureListener?

The problem with HorizontalScrollView is that I can't have more than 1 child.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483567/how-to-make-right-or-left-or-left-to-right-transition-between-activities-on-slid

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for a ViewPager, here's a description of them and a video of how it works - http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

You'll have to use Fragments rather than Activities and if you want to do them on older versions of Android you'll need to use the support library.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for ViewPager, also have a look at this [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)