# Best way to init Activities in ViewPager

Tags: android

I would like to write app with some activities in ViewPager, so I'm writing smth like this:

```
calendarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar, null);
calendarView.setTag(getString("tag"));
```

Initing of a single view is quite a lot code. In fact I have 3 views, so initing of all of them looks like terrible. I'm just curious are there any other (correct) way of dealing with ViewPager?

Comment: Use separate fragments with the ViewPager.

Comment: You don't swipe between `Activities`, you need to convert them into `Fragments`. [Here's an example, it's very simple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9849234/420015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure if I got what you want, but a good way of modularization is using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Pack-up your views + functionality in a Fragment and return each Fragment accordingly on `getItem`([FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) method). There is a source code on Android Training here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging