# Android:Change "screens" when swiping

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I want to make something like this in my android app

[image]

With 2 or 3 activities or more. I don't want to use visible tabs with names. I just want when i slide through a new activity with its own layout appear, a totally different screen. I've read about viewpager and pageradapter, but i' m a little confused. What do you think is the best way to do it?

Comment: Viewpager will be your solution.

Comment: or you can use viewflipper

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html

Comment: Learn fragments and viewpager to smoothly achieve your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually create a swiping activity in android studio.

**Goto:**

**File -> New -> Activity -> Tabbed Activity** and choose **Navigation Style** to be **Swipe Views.**

Android Studio will do the rest. Then you can change the fragments according to your need.

**EDIT:**

This is a nice example that demonstrate using `Activity` with `ViewPager`.

[Android PagerView between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849138/android-pagerview-between-activities)

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need, just follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

You dont even need multiples activities.

Comment: There will be something like different apps performing it that tabs, why i don't need different activities?

Comment: Cause in each Fragment you can do what you want and perform exactly the same things that you would have done in an activity.

You really should try this tutorial, design is good and easy to understand and you can even just C/C

Comment: Link is dead...