# How do i supposed to change activity on swipe write in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to change activity on swipe right as instagram does to open messanger in android app.

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: those are fragments inside ViewPager, not activities

Answer (score 1):

Instagram is written in react native, so there might be some things that are impossible to recreate natively.

Take a look here [Android PagerView between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849138/android-pagerview-between-activities)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments). You can implement your intended functionality using [View pager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) or something similar.